# Troubles installing Exchange 2019 CU12 remotely

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2019

Afternoon,

I'm running into an issue with making a script that will install Exchange 2019 CU12 on a server through PS Remoting.

When I try to run the commands

```
Invoke-Command $Hostname -ScriptBlock {

    # Extend the schema and Prepare Active Directory
    Write-Output 'Extending Active Directory Schema and Preparing Active Directory...'
    & C:\EXCH\Exchange_2019_CU12\Setup.exe /prepareAD /OrganizationName:"$env:USERDOMAIN" /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms_DiagnosticDataOFF

    Write-Output 'Preparing Domain...'
    & C:\EXCH\Exchange_2019_CU12\Setup.exe /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms_DiagnosticDataOFF /PrepareAllDomains

}
```

it errors out with

```
C:\EXCH\Exchange_2019_CU12\Setup.exe : Global updates need to be made to Active Directory, and this user account isn't
a member of the 'Enterprise Admins' group.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Global updates ... Admins' group.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Active Directory must be prepared with 'Setup /PrepareAD' before domains can be prepared for Exchange Server.
Setup encountered a problem while validating the state of Active Directory: Active Directory operation failed on . The
supplied credential for 'V204\tdcadmin' is invalid.  See the Exchange setup log for more information on this error.
The forest functional level of the current Active Directory forest is not Windows Server 2012 R2 or later. To install
Exchange Server 2019, the forest functional level must be at least Windows Server 2012 R2.
Either Active Directory doesn't exist, or it can't be contacted.
```

I'm logged into the computer with an account that is part of the appropriate groups.

If I log onto the server with the same account and run the commands locally, it works with no issues.

Am I missing something with my remote commands?

Comment: Double hop issue. Your remoting to a box that needs to query ad, the dreaded second hop.

Comment: Hmm never thought about that but makes sense… appreciate it